# Runtime Error on Website (asp.net versions mismatch)

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm quite new to this and was playing around with a website today. I decided that, since I had tinkered with most pages I'd just upload the whole thing via Filezilla anew but when I tried to access the website afterwards I only got this:

> ## Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

I have backups and tried uploading them (again - the whole thing) but its coming up with the same error. What should I do to get my site back online?

Answer (score 0):

Check the application pool the website is using matches the .net framework version site was developed using. Amend the IIS application pool to match and restart the site.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly. The deal is, I have no idea how to do this. Could you please give me specific instructions?
Cheers,
Ivo

Comment: Hi Ivo. It depends on how the site is hosted. If you have access to the server via RDP you can do this via IIS admin MMC. If you only have FTP access to the hosting resource then in my experience admin user credentials will have access to a web control panel UI managed by the resource supplier. From this UI you should have ability to define the environmental variables for the resource i.e .net 3.5 , .net 4.0 etc. Ask whoever supplied you with the FTP credentials. I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I the application is targetting .Net framework 4.5 the problem is I how do I find out what version my server has if the only thing I get is an error screen?

Comment: If the environmental variables are not displayed in error page then best approach is to find that someone somewhere that will have administrative access to the environment in order to define these variables.  Please contact that person, most likely the person that supplied your FTP credentials. In most cases there is a web interface for FTP sites that allow you to define the site particulars.

Comment: Found it. It Says that the website asp.net is v4.0. I've tried to compile the app to .net framework 4.0 however everything seems to go wrong from there (getting hundreds of errors). I can't select 4.5 on the website or IIS Manager

Comment: Hello @scott_lotus! I noticed you've made a lot of edits to questions that change the format. I've asked a question about this type of edit on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314645/edits-that-separate-questions-into-a-problem-question-part). Thought you'd want to be involved in the discussion.